# Internal error: unknown GenerateMaterial type: 2282272

Tags: unity3d

Был проект на *Unity 4.6*, поставил последнюю *Unity 5.0.1*, вылез ряд ошибок:

1. > Internal error: unknown GenerateMaterial type: 2282272
2. > You are trying to import an asset which contains a global game manager. This is not allowed.

Как их исправить?